# RISC-V returns are hanging

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, riscv, gnu-assembler

```
                                                                                                                                                                                            
.data
.align 3
format_string:
        .string "hello, dummy! %s %d\n"

tmp_x:
        .word 0  # Initialize tmp_x with a value of 0

        .set foo, 100

.text
.globl main

main:
        li a0, 10
        li a1, 20
        li a2, 2
        li a3, 0
        li a4, foo
loop:
        # Load the value from tmp_x into a5
        lw a5, tmp_x
        j print
        slli a3, a3, 2
        blt a3, a4, loop

print:
        # Set up arguments for printf
        la a0, format_string  # Load the address of the format string
        mv a1, a5            # Move the value in a5 to a1 (integer to print)
        call printf          # Use "printf" for formatted output
    # ret
    jalr x0, 0(x1)

exit:
        li a0, 0
        li a7, 93
        ecall
```

It is strange, but the program never returns from the print. It calls printf and works correctly up to that point, but when I try to use ret it just sits there doing nothing. I've attempted to use jalr to return, but same problem.

When I use gdb, it appears to return from the printf call and move to ret (before I commented it) or jalr, but nothing is happening. It will not step to next instruction.

Anyone have any ideas I could try?

Comment: `call printf` overwrites the link register; you need to save / restore it on the stack.  Look at compiler output for a function that calls printf and returns something else (so it can't tailcall), https://godbolt.org/

Comment: When you're debugging, look at the registers.  Many will change value stepping over `printf`, some registers you don't care if they change, but others are holding important variables/values, like `ra`.

Comment: Although I haven't fixed it the way I wanted. The problem is that the printf call is stomping all over the ra register. So I've modified it to just do a straight jump back to the function. (although I had to re-write the calling loop.

Comment: On the side, is .align 3 (3 byte alignment) intentional?

Comment: It was intentional, but I can't remember why now. I've taken it out though.